# Is AMD Turion™ 64 X2 really 64 bit?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, central-processing-unit

I've HP Pavilion Notebook (db6000). It has AMD Turion™ 64 X2. It came pre-installed with Windows Vista Home Premium. I smoked it and installed Vista again. But in spite of it being touted at 64bit I was not able to install Vista 64 bit version. It only allows 32 bit one. So I'm wondering if the processor is really 64 bit or a marketing gimmic for 32 +32 = 64 bit [it is dual core for sure :) ]

EDIT:- ***Why am I not able to install 64-bit version of Vista if the processor is 64-bit?***

Comment: What is the Vista installation reporting when it fails?

Comment: I'd recommend you asking a different question about Vista 64 failing to install with further detail, such as the error message. I'd also recommend you to accept SZayat's answer, because that was the asked question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Turion 64 X2 is a 64-bit CPU. Run [SecurAble](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm) to be extra sure ;)

Comment: the why can't I install Vista 64 bit?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: You're going to have to tell us what happened when you tried. How far did you get? What went wrong? It could be anything, but it's not the CPU.

Comment: @David Schwartz actaully the dvd was 32bit :D

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a [Linux LiveCD AMD64](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download) version just to prove your processor can run an AMD64 operating system.

I guess we'll need more information to work out the Vista problem - might it be one of the other requirements that your system isn't meeting?